# How to handle when keyboard display on TextInput in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, keyboard, textinput

I am new in react native.

I have my form like this

```
<View style={{flex:1, flexDirection='row'}}>
  <View style={flex:1, flexDirection='column', justifyContent='center}}> //left

    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <TextInput placeholder='TEST' />
    </View>

  </View>

  <View style={flex:1, flexDirection='column', justifyContent='center' }}> //right

    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <TextInput placeholder='TEST' />
    </View>

  </View>
</View>
```

My form has 2 side left and right.

when I run npm start (I started by create-rect-native-app) in simulator.

then I click input tab. iOS's keyboard appear and lap to the input tab.

When I type something, I can't see what happen in input tab.

Is there any solution without using ScrollView?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap all with [KeyboardAvoidingView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.46/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html#keyboardavoidingview) it will take care of moving input when keyboard showed

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding"  style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}} >
    <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:'center' }} >

      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TextInput placeholder='TEST' />
      </View>

    </View>

    <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:'center' }}>

      <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
        <TextInput placeholder='TEST' />
      </View>

    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: Thank you, I used it at first, but it was not work. Maybe I missed about style